# How to dynamically create variable with loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, dynamic, queryselector

How to re-write this code with loop?

```
var einput1 = document.querySelector("#email0").value;
var einput2 = document.querySelector("#email1").value;
var einput3 = document.querySelector("#email2").value;
```

and also how to access a specific variable from that loop? Thank You.

Edit:-
Here is demo-

```js
//fuction to genrate email field
function emailGen() {
  var quant = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  for (a = 0; a < quant; a++) {
    var emailGen = document.createElement("input");
    emailGen.type = "email";
    emailGen.id = "email" + a;
    emailGen.placeholder = "Member's Email";
    container.appendChild(emailGen);
  }

}


var form = document.getElementById("nameForm");
// event
form.addEventListener("submit", tableGen);
//function for table generator
function tableGen(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tblbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  var input1 = document.querySelector("#input1").value;
  var quan = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;
  //my question is here :-how to make this loop 
  var einput1 = document.querySelector("#email0").value;
  var einput2 = document.querySelector("#email1").value;
  var einput3 = document.querySelector("#email2").value;


  //table rows loop
  for (i = 0; i <= quan; i++) {
    var tblrow = document.createElement("tr");

    //table coloumn loop
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      var tbldata = document.createElement("td");

      if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        var pname = document.createTextNode(input1);
        tbldata.appendChild(pname);
      }
      if (i == 1 && j == 0) {
        var tname = document.createTextNode(einput1);
        tbldata.appendChild(tname);
      }
      if (i == 2 && j == 0) {
        var tname = document.createTextNode(einput2);
        tbldata.appendChild(tname);
      }
      if (i == 3 && j == 0) {
        var tname = document.createTextNode(einput3);
        tbldata.appendChild(tname);
      }
      tblrow.appendChild(tbldata);
    }

    tblbody.appendChild(tblrow);

  }
  table.appendChild(tblbody);
  body.appendChild(table);
  table.setAttribute("border", "4");
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Name"><br/>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Total Members(max 10)" min="1" max="10">
  <button type="button" id="okButton" onclick="emailGen()">  OK  </button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="tableGen()">
</form>
```

It only show table when input is 3 because declared variable are 3 (at the starting of question) and if I want to submit 1 or 2 field , it does not get submitted. if there is any way to create variable from loop and access it like I did here (einput1)

`var tname = document.createTextNode(einput1);`

Comment: https://github.com/PriyalChauhan/Work-From-Home-Toolbox/blob/master/create-project-icon.js.            Sir , this is my code. Html and JavaScript both are in this repo.

Comment: WHere is the HTML in that and where is the expected output and examples

Comment: HTML is here (https://github.com/PriyalChauhan/PriyalChauhan.github.io)   and example is here (https://priyalchauhan.github.io/#)

Comment: Please click create button and give it a name and than click next. Enter less than 3 ( 3 works fine because in code I have declared 3 variables) try to submit it. Also I have edited the question again but it is closed :(

Comment: Please update the question with enough code to have a [mcve] - it is not clear what you mean by _call a specific variable from that loop_

Comment: Sir, I have updated it with my best efforts. Please take a look at it and provide if any answer is available. Thank you for your continuous replys.

Comment: I also cleaned your snippet and corrected your invalid `</br>`

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the emails a name to submit them

Also I removed the onsubmit form the submit button. It does not belong there and can be removed. You have a submit event handler and that should do it

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
document.getElementById("nameForm").addEventListener("submit", tableGen);
document.getElementById("okButton").addEventListener("click", emailGen);


//fuction to genrate email field
function emailGen() {
  const quant = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
    var emailGen = document.createElement("input");
    emailGen.type = "email";
    emailGen.id = "email" + i;
    emailGen.name = "email" + i;
    emailGen.placeholder = "Member's Email";
    container.appendChild(emailGen);
  }
}


//function for table generator
function tableGen(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  const tblbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  const input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  const quan = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  const emails = container.querySelectorAll("[type=email]")

  console.log(emails.length)

  //table rows loop
  for (let i = 0; i < quan; i++) {
    const tblrow = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
      const tblcell = document.createElement("td");
      //table column loop
      const pname = document.createTextNode(input1);
      tblcell.appendChild(pname);
      const tname = document.createTextNode(emails[j].value);
      tblcell.appendChild(tname);
      tblrow.appendChild(tblcell);
    }


    tblbody.appendChild(tblrow);

  }
  console.log
  table.appendChild(tblbody);
  body.appendChild(table);
  table.setAttribute("border", "4");
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Name"><br/>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Total Members(max 10)" min="1" max="10">
  <button type="button" id="okButton">OK</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Previous answer

```js
document.getElementById("emailForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
  const quan = +document.getElementById("quan").value
  const addr = Array.from({length: quan}, (_, i) => `<input id="email${i}" type="email" placeholder="email${i}" />`)
  this.innerHTML += addr.join('<br/>')
})
```

```html
<form id="emailForm">
  <input type="number" min=1 max=10 id="quan" /><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. It is working exactly as I wanted. This line helped a lot ( `const emails = container.querySelectorAll("[type=email]")` ) even without the need of loop it worked fine and also thank you for your patience with my questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop & string interpolation to achieve the desired results.

The `inputs` array stores DOM nodes and then you can iterate over this to get the value as in the `console.log` below OR you can store the values in the `input` array if you don't want the DOM nodes anymore.

```js
const quan = 3;
const inputs = Array.from({ length: quan }, (_, index) =>
  document.querySelector(`#email${index}`)
);

console.log(inputs.map((inp) => inp.value));
```

```html
<input id="email0" type="email" value="value0">
<input id="email1" type="email" value="value1">
<input id="email2" type="email" value="value2">
```